# Oracle ApEx calculating

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In Oracle ApEx I want to calculate/sum different items and hidden items to a result and then use the result as a database column.

[image: The items]

The contents of the above items circled(squared) by the larger red border need to be multiplied by eachother and the result needs to be put into the smaller one.

P3_PRIJS is put into a database column after submitting the form.

***As always, thank you for helping me and taking me seriously.***

Comment: Do you want calculation on change of any Item?

Comment: As soon as I submit the page(Which puts the data in the database, as well as the P3_PRIJS item) it needs to calculate the values that are put in the ones with the red border and put into P3_PRIJS

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using page Computation.

1. Create a page computation (which should fire after the page substitution), Select Location as **Item on This Page**.
2. Select Compute Item as :P3_PRIJS and provide the sequence number and select  **Computation Toint** as **After Submit** and select **Computation Type** as **SQL Query(return single value)**.
3. Enter the Computation as

   ```
   select :p3_para1 * :p3_para2 * :p3_para3 * :p3_para4 * :p3_para5 * :p3_para6  from dual;
   ```

   4.Provide condition type if needed (not mandatory).

Comment: The above process is for setting value to item **P3_PRIJS** alone.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Create a *process* with type: *PL/SQL* (it should be set to that be default).

**2)** Enter the following code:

```
DECLARE
    INSERT_VALUE NUMBER;
BEGIN
    --this does your calculations
    INSERT_VALUE := :P3_AANTAL_IMPRESSIES * :P3_FORMAAT_INDEX_KOSTEN * :P3_INTERESSE_INDEX_KOSTEN * :P3_SELECTIE_INDEX_KOSTEN * :P3_PROFIEL_INDEX_GESLACHT_KOSTEN * :P3_PROFIEL_INDEX_LEEFTIJD_KOSTEN;

    --this will set your bottom value session state.  You could comment out the following line if needed.
    APEX_UTIL.set_session_state('P3_PRIJS', INSERT_VALUE);

    --this inserts your value into your database
    INSERT INTO you_table (column_one,column_two,column_three)
    VALUES(
    INSERT_VALUE,
    second_value,
    third_value
    );

END;
```

**4)** Set the *point* of the *process* to *processing*

**4)** Double check my work

**Things to note:**
 This will set the session state of your variable once the page is submitted.  If you would like to set the session state of your variable before the page is submitted you will probably need to use the code that sets your bottom value in a dynamic action.  Also if you use this method it will save resources if by allowing you to not use the page item :P3_PRIJS.  I hope this helps!